# Difference between Semantic error and logical error

Tags: php

from some articles I read on *general programming concept*. I was made to know that "syntaxs are the formal rules that governs the construct of valid statement in a language" while "semantics are set of rules that give meaning to a statement of a language". from the defination of semantics, I feel it is similar to logic, if not, then please I want to know the difference between **logical error** and **semantic error**?

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be lot of confusion around the definition of these terms, but here's my understanding:

Syntax relate to spelling and grammar.

Logic relate to program flow.

Semantics relate to meaning and context.

If the code fails to execute due to typos, invalid names, a missing parenthesis or some other grammatical flaw, you have a syntax error.

If the syntax is correct but a piece of code is (inadvertently) never executed, operations are not done in the correct order, the operation itself is wrong or code is operating on the wrong data, you have a logical error. Using a wrong conditional operator is a common example, so is inadvertently creating an infinite loop or mixing up (valid) names of variables or functions.

If both your program logic and syntax is correct so the code runs as intended, but the result is still wrong: you likely have a semantic error. Confusing a metric input value for an imperial value will get you there. Nothing wrong with the program, except that miles and kilometres don't add up, so your area calculation throws out the wrong number. Having a race condition is another common example.

Comment: I would like to point out that using invalid/undefined variable names is a runtime error, not a syntax error but a great answer overall

Comment: Fair point, @AmirWG, even if one could say that would also depend on the language - many compilers would detect undefined variables. To be clear, I had syntactically incorrect names in mind when I wrote that. On a side note, I would be tempted to argue that many runtime errors are also syntax errors, even if some definitions of the term exclude them by default. Interpreted languages make these distinctions vague.

Answer (score 3):

The answer here depends on the book you are reading or the class you are in. In many areas of Computer Science, there is absolutely no difference between a Semantic Error and a Logic Error. Both mean that the program compiled, but the output was wrong. Just as often, they mean two different things. A simple example is intending to use X+1 in your program, but you typed X-1. That is a Logic Error. If you typed X+true, it would be Syntax Error if the language allowed it to pass through the parser, but the result of X+(boolean true) wasn't the same as X+1. Personally, when it comes to poorly defined terms such as this, I let people define them how they like and just remove the errors from my programs, regardless of what kind of errors they are.

Answer (score 0):

Basically differentiating semantic errors and logic errors is contradictory as, first both in programming produce an result that is not to the expected function of the program and secondly logic errors result in semantic error as the program runs against expected functioning.

Answer (score -2):

Just Google it thousands of answer will be in front of you with brief.

Semantic error is related to the meaning of something. it mean that it is a violation of the rules of meaning of a natural language or a programming language , suppose we are using the programming statement improperly ..the semantic error will be detected at compile time.

and the logical error is that Errors that indicate the logic used when coding the program failed to solve the problem. The logic error will not cause the program to stop working but our desired result will not be get.

if you want to see the example go to this site.....
http://newtutorial2012.blogspot.com/2012/07/differentced-between-synataxsemantic.html

Comment: thanks for your direction. I will check out the link you provided.

Comment: Welcome and Good luck

Comment: Semantic errors will not be detected at compile time, they occur only at execution time, so you need to test for them. Perhaps you were thinking of syntax errors?